# Javascript Object Literal Scope Issue?

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I'm having a hard time understanding why `this.$map` and `this.markers` are undefined.  Here's the code I'm working with and I have added comments where I expect these variables to supply a value:

```
(function($) {
    'use strict';

    var A = {

        /**
         * Initialize the A object
         */
        init: function() {
            this.$map = this.renderMap();
            this.markers = this.getMarkers();

            this.renderMarkers();
        },

        renderMap: function() {

            var url = 'http://a.tiles.mapbox.com/v3/delewis.map-i3eukewg.jsonp';

            // Get metadata about the map from MapBox
            wax.tilejson(url, function(tilejson) {
                var map = new L.Map('map', {zoomControl: false});

                var ma = new L.LatLng(42.2625, -71.8028);

                map.setView(ma, 8);

                // Add MapBox Streets as a base layer
                map.addLayer(new wax.leaf.connector(tilejson));

                return function() {
                    return map;
                };
            });
        },

        renderMarkers: function() {
            var geojsonLayer = new L.GeoJSON(null, {
                pointToLayer: function (latlng){
                    return new L.CircleMarker(latlng, {
                        radius: 8,
                        fillColor: "#ff7800",
                        color: "#000",
                        weight: 1,
                        opacity: 1,
                        fillOpacity: 0.8
                    });
                }
            });

            geojsonLayer.addGeoJSON(this.markers); // this.markers is undefined
            this.$map.addLayer(geojsonLayer); // this.$map is undefined

        },

        getMarkers: function() {
            $.getJSON("/geojson/", function (data) {
                return data;
            });
        }
    };

    /**
     * A interactions
     */
    $(document).ready(function() {
        A.init()
    });

})(jQuery.noConflict());
```

I have spent much of the day searching and I think I'm missing something fundamental here, but I don't get it.

Comment: Because you cannot (lets say should not) return values from an Ajax call... Ajax is **asynchronous** by default. If you could return the value directly, why would you have to pass a callback? Please read [jQuery: Return data after ajax call success](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5316697/jquery-return-data-after-ajax-call-success). It's partly a scope issue, but mostly a timing issue.

Comment: Look at `getMarkers`. The function does not return a value. The callback you pass to `$.getJSON` does, but that callback is executed by (inside) `$.getJSON`, so it returns the value to `$.getJSON` and not the function that calls `getMarkers`. Furthermore, the callback is executed when the response was received and at that time `getMarkers` already finished (returned `undefined`). There are literally (I assume) thousands of questions here which are about the same problem.

Comment: There must be thousands, easily. One day I counted 8 new "async thing doesn't return a value" questions in a few hours. Assuming there are about 8 of these posted a day, that would be about thirty thousand over the lifespan of the site so far.

Comment: @GGG, I didn't realize both scenarios were an ajax call. Stupid on my part? Yes, and it had me looking in the wrong place.

Comment: @MarkLewis the fact that you're passing callbacks to functions with "json" in the name should be a pretty big hint that the functions you are calling are ascynchonous, and the fact that you're returning things from callbacks should be a red flag.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Neither the `renderMap`, nor `getMarkers` methods return any value, consequently their return value is `undefined`.

It looks like you are trying to initialize these fields from an ajax request, which is not necessarily a good idea.

What you probably ought to do is something like:

```
getMarkers: function(callback){
    var result = this;
    $.getJSON("url", function(jsonData){ 
        result.markers = jsonData; 
        if(callback) callback()
     });
},
```

which will lazily initialize the fields of the object as they become available.

**NB**: AJAX is **asynchronous** you cannot rely on this callback setting the member quickly, or indeed ever (it could fail).
This suggests you need to think a bit more about your design, and try to use callbacks more.

e.g. modify the `getMarkers` and `renderMap` functions as above to take a callback that is called after the data is stored then change init to:

```
init: function(){
    var res = this;
    var post_init_callback = function(){
        if(res.$map != undefined && res.markers!=undefined){
            //this will only run after both ajax calls are complete
            res.renderMarkers();  
        }
    };
    this.getMarkers(post_init_callback);
    this.renderMap(post_init_callback);
},
```

Comment: So instead of trying to return the data to a variable, I should utilize a callback to process the data? In the case of `renderMap()` how what I return `map`?

Comment: Add `var result = this;` at the top of render map, and change `return map` to `result.$map = map;` also, see my edit

Comment: WOW, your comment just made me realize that `wax.tilejson` is an ajax call. Now I understand, I thought I had two different situations. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you call return inside another function. What you're essentially doing is defining `getMarkers` (the simplest example) as this:

```
getMarkers: function() {
    $.getJSON('/geojson/', some_random_func);
}
```

At which point it becomes obious that getMarkers doesn't actually return anything (ergo undefined). The same goes for your renderMap function. Also in this case your "some_random_func" is defined as `function(data) { return data; }` but what does it return it to? Truth is that the `some_random_func` is called by jQuery itself, and AFAIK jQuery doesn't care at all for the return-value of it's success-function.

Comment: Doesn't it return the data to `this.markers` in `A.init()` (i.e. `this.markers = this.getMarkers();`)?

Comment: @Mark: The function `getMarkers` does not have a `return` statement, how can it return anything? Maybe you are confused by the function you define inside `getMarkers`... the value that that function returns is not magically returned by `getMarkers` (there might be languages where this is the case, but not in JavaScript). You can make a simple test: What does `function foo() { function bar() { return 'bar';} bar(); }; alert(foo());` give you?

Comment: @Felix, your comments help, thank you.  Now I just need to understand the solution.